# Wordpress Database Cleanup

Tags: multisite, database, management

How hard would it be to rebuild a WordPress database and change the directory structure for a website? I inherited the maintenance of two websites and I am pretty sure the directory structure is set up incorrectly and the database is a total mess (6 databases for two websites?).

I am new to WordPress and suspect that at this point it would be easier just to rebuild the website using the existing one. Losing data is not a big deal and the website does nothing fancy. The website works but it has been becoming more difficult to maintain.

Is this a reasonable plan?

Answer (score 0):

WP is designed to use a single database.  In fact you can have several sites in a single database because they'd each use a different table prefix.

How difficult it'll be to cleanup will depend on the code involved.  I'd be mostly concerned that since the previous developer (I use the term loosely) didn't use WordPress coding standards, they likely used older PHP standards if any at all, and the databases may be accessed with the older, deprecated, mysql_* library.

Yes, if it's not going to be a lot of trouble to do so, I'd definitely rebuild from the ground up.

Comment: I think that answers my question. I think the easiest way to fix it will be just to rebuild it using wordpress coding standards. Thanks

Comment: As far as directory structure goes, you have to make sure you update all  the urls in the database.  There is a plugin (velvet blues i think) that can help with that. (eg if you move wp into it's own directory https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)